# Flux through circle

Tags: calculus

[Vector field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Miz.png)

Question: The flux through a circle of r = 1 and center (0,0) (counterclockwise)?

Comment: You need to show your effort. Can you please edit your question stating what you tried and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flux is defined as

$$\int_{|r|=1} F\cdot d\vec S$$

Here, $d\vec S$ is an infinitesimal piece of the disc, pointing in the normal direction in counterclockwise orientation. Can you think of what $d\vec S$ would be? You may want to choose an appropriate coordinate system.